# postfix how to hold sender's mail submitted bvia sendmail command

Tags: postfix

I have a sender on my postfix host submitting mail via the sendmail (or mail) command.

I sometimes need to hold mail from that specific sender in the postfix Hold queue, instead of delivering it immediately.

IOW, I'm looking for the equivalent of:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/*somefile*
```

where the entry in *somefile* is set to HOLD.

But, since this particular sender is submitting the mail via the sendmail (or mail) command, it's not filtered by smtpd_sender_restrictions

Is there some other way I can hold this mail?

Answer (score 0):

I think about the only place you can do that sort of filtering in mail dropped into the local maildrop is via `header_checks`.

A totally untested example:

```
/From: .*user@example.com/ HOLD
```

Comment: Thanks for a great idea. But the HOLD action contains this caveat "This feature is not supported with smtp header/body checks" :-(  See http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html

Comment: But I tried it anyway - and it works!!

Comment: @flymike It works because it was done in `cleanup(8)`, not in SMTP.